# Unable to run a process as another user created by "useradd" with no password

Tags: sudo, user-management, arch-linux

I've created a user for running a certain process only on behalf of that user:

```
sudo useradd -r -s /bin/false -d /var/lib/my_app123 my_user123
```

Now in order to run that process from behalf of "my_user123", I'm doing this:

```
su - my_user123
```

1) And it asks me a password. What password? there's no password for "my_user123". How to fix this?

2) Or what's the proper way to run "/var/lib/my_app123/some_process" as "my_user123"?

sudo itself is working fine.

Comment: You're using `su` above, but your tags and question seems to be about `sudo`. Those are not the same tool.

Comment: @TollefFogHeen, what do you mean by "seem"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can specify the right system shell:

```
su - youruser -s /bin/bash -c "yourcommand"
```

Or run the commands with sudo, it's gonna work even if youruser doesn't have a valid shell, like in your case.

Or you can't be able to log in with su as you specified /bin/false as shell for youruser. That's why the system's asking for a password.

Comment: `su - youruser -s /bin/bash -c "yourcommand"` - requires the password

Comment: You're running this command as normal user?

Comment: yes.................

Comment: Then the server's asking for the user's password who runs su, and that's normal. :)

Comment: can I run a daemon under another user and switch back to my default user? will a daemon continue to run?

Comment: Try to google for "Linux shell fork process in background"

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` and `su` are totally different programs. This is how [`su`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Su) works: if you aren't root, it asks for the password of the target (`su`bstitute) user. The condition that you haven't yet set password doesn't change this; use [`passwd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html) to add a password for the user. If you need to run commands as another user without knowing or giving that user's password, you should use `sudo`, instead.

> From a security perspective, it is arguably better to set up and use
>   [sudo](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo) instead of `su`. The `sudo` system will prompt you for your own
>   password – or no password at all, if configured in such a way – rather
>   than that of the target user (the user account you are attempting to
>   use). This way you do not have to share passwords between users, and
>   if you ever need to stop a user having root access (or access to any
>   other account, for that matter), you do not have to change the root
>   password, which is an inconvenience to everyone else; you only need to
>   revoke that user's sudo access.

The `sudo` equivalent for `su - user` is `sudo -u user -s`. If you wish to do this without using your own password, you need to [`visudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/visudo.man.html) and add this line to your [`sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html) file:

```
yourusername    ALL=(anotheruser) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash
```

This gives `yourusername` permission to run `/bin/bash` as user `anotheruser` without password.

Comment: `The condition that you haven't yet set password doesn't change this. ` -- what password? whose?

Comment: The `su`bstitute user ("`my_user123`") you are trying to run the command as. Added clarification.

Comment: but I haven't set a password for him. what password should I use?

Comment: Read the answer to the end without stopping every time you don't understand some detail. It may get explained later in the answer – this time within the next sentences.